# Define properties like CSS class types using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using the below dropdown in 4 places in one page is there a way to define the font-size at one place like we do it in CSS, using the ASP control `Font-Size`. Is that possible to do it in ASP.NET page

```
<asp:DropDownList Font-Size="XX-Small" runat="server" ID="SampleDropDown"  >
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is always preferable to use a CSS class name + stylesheet over inline styles.

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dropDownListA" runat="server" ID="SampleDropDown" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

CSS:

```
.dropDownListA {
     font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Which one I use em or px. Do ASP.NET prefers any of these..considering compatiblity with all the browsers